# Map pattern matching in function head

Tags: erlang, pattern-matching

I'm trying to make a function that accepts two arguments, a tuple consisting of three elements, and a map that will assign the last two elements in the tuple values. so for example I would call the function like this

```
modulename:funcName({description, a,b}, #{a=>1, b=>2)).
```

I cannot get the pattern matching to work. My function as it is looks like this

```
funcName({description,a,b}, #{a:=A, b:=2}.
```

I cannot get the atoms in the tuple to be mapped to the value in the map. How do I go about this.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you want correctly, this isn't possible to do in the function head itself, because all variables used as map keys must be previously bound.  From [the OTP 23 highlights blog post](https://blog.erlang.org/OTP-23-Highlights/#matching-on-maps):

> Below there is an illegal example showing that it is still not supported to use an unbound variable as part of the expression for the key-pattern. In this case Key is not bound and the requirement is that all variables used in a key expression must be previously bound.
>
> ```
> illegal_example(Key, #{Key := Value}) -> Value.
> ```

So you'd have to write something like this:

```
func_name({description, Key1, Key2}, Map = #{}) ->
    #{Key1 := Value1, Key2 := Value2} = Map,
    ....
```

This works because on the second line the variables `Key1` and `Key2` are already bound, so they can be used to match out the values of the corresponding keys in the map.

Alternatively, use `maps:get` to achieve the same result:

```
func_name({description, Key1, Key2}, Map = #{}) ->
    Value1 = maps:get(Key1, Map),
    Value2 = maps:get(Key2, Map),
    ....
```

Comment: Doesn't this Map#{} call for an empty map? I do not understand where I would get Value1 and Value2 from since it is an empty map

Comment: No, in a pattern match `#{}` stands for any map, empty or not. The same effect could be achieved by adding `when is_map(Map)`. This is just to get a descriptive error if the second argument is not a map, though you could say that the badmatch error you'd get on the next line is just as clear.

Comment: ok, but I still don't understand where Value1 and Value2 comes from. Should I use maps:get/2 to acquire the values?

Comment: `Value1` and `Value2` become bound to the values of the corresponding keys in the map through the pattern match. You could use `maps:get` as well - I added an example of that.

Comment: Ok, I changed my code to this https://ibb.co/dKvq99f but I still get this warning and error https://ibb.co/dKvq99fhttps://ibb.co/R9TC53P. I still can't map atoms to values with my code

Comment: Looks like you'd need to modify `X` to insert `Value1` and `Value2` before you pass it to `eval/1`. Currently, `X` is `{add,a,b}` when you call `eval/2`, and the `eval(X)` call passes it on unchanged.

Comment: Any suggestion on how to do that? Because that's the crux of the problem really. I want to be able to map any potential atom in the tuple X according the values mapped to these atoms in Map

Comment: Something like `eval(X, Map) when is_atom(X) -> maps:get(X, Map)` to get the values from variables, and then `eval({add, X, Y}, Map) -> eval(X, Map) + eval(Y, Map)` for the actual operation.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in 2 steps (to keep the pattern matching at the function head level):

```
funcName(T = {description,A,B}, Map) ->
    funcName(T, maps:get(Map,A,undefined), maps:get(Map,B,undefined), Map).

funcName({description,a,b}, A, 2, Map) when A =/= undefined ->
    ...
```

**Edit**

I just re-read your question and now don't understand what is not working. It can be done in one step, with your code (and a small syntax correction):

```
-module (test).

-export ([funcName/2]).

funcName({description,a,b}, #{a := A, b := 2}) ->
    A;
funcName(_,_) ->
    error.
```

and you can test it:

```
1> test:funcName({description,a,b},#{a => "hello", b => 2}).
"hello"
2> test:funcName({description,a,b},#{a => "hello", b => 3}).
error
3> test:funcName({description,a,b},#{a => "hello", c => 2}).
error
4> test:funcName({description,a,b},#{aa => "hello", b => 2}).
error
5> test:funcName({description,a,bb},#{a => "hello", b => 2}).
error
6> test:funcName({description,a,b,c},#{a => "hello", b => 2}).
error
7>
```

Comment: Maybe I should have been more clear. The input of the function should be able to be something like modulename:funcname({description,a,b},#{a=>2,b=3}). So I don't understand how this funcName({description,a,b}, #{a := A, b := 2}) ->
A;  can be the solution. The value mapped atom b isn't supposed to be determined in the function header, it's to be determined by the input