# Matching values in a tuple through a map

Tags: tuples, erlang, pattern-matching

I'm trying to make a function like this essentially

```
eval(X, Map = #{}) ->
%% expression
.
```

X is supposed to be a tuple that will contain three elements, with the first one being a description. The other values can be either integers, or they can be the atom a or b, or another tuple. The second parameter  is supposed  to be a map that will map any potential atom a or b in X to a value. Example inputs can be

```
eval({add, a, b}, #{a => 1, b => 2})
```

```
eval({add, a, 2}, #{a => 1})
```

```
eval({mul, {add, a, 3}, b}, #{a => 1, b => 2}).
```

I for the life of me cannot find a way to have Map, map any potential atom a or b in X to the values given in the input. Anyone has a suggestion for how to implement so that any atom a or b are mapped to vales given in Map?

Comment: Is this a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66799585 ?

Comment: What does "have a Map map any potential atom a or b in X to the values given in the input" mean?  How much easier would it have been to give an example of the output for each of your examples ather than make people try to decipher that tortured sentence?

Comment: It is my question, but I realized I wasn't perfectly clear with what I wanted answered. As I couldn't delete my question, I felt I had no choice but to write a new question that better described what I wanted answered. this input eval({mul, {add, a, 3}, b}, #{a => 1, b => 2}) would have as output 8, as it would in my program function as 4*2  through eval({mul, {add, 1, 3}, 2}, #{a => 1, b => 2}) which in my program would be (3+1)*2

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by other folks at [Map pattern matching in function head](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66799585) (Although this question has a far clearer description), what you are looking for is something along the lines of…

```
eval({Op, a, b}, #{a := A, b := B}) ->
    eval(Op, A, B);
eval({Op, A, b}, #{b := B}) ->
    eval(Op, A, B);
eval({Op, a, B}, #{a := A}) ->
    eval(Op, A, B);
eval({Op, A, B}, _) ->
    eval(Op, A, B).

eval(add, A, B) ->
    A + B;
eval(mul, A, B) ->
    A * B;
…
```

Comment: First of all, thanks for the help, now the program works, in a partial respect. These two input works, eval({add, a, b}, #{a => 1, b => 2}), eval({add, a, 2}, #{a => 1}), but not this input eval({mul, {add, a, 3}, b}, #{a => 1, b => 2}). It creates this error message exception error: an error occurred when evaluating an arithmetic expression
     in operator  +/2
        called as a + 3
     in call from task1:eval/1 (task1.erl, line 15)
     in call from task1:eval/1 (task1.erl, line 18)

Comment: @RasmusSteen,  Whatever you do, don't post line 15 and line 18 of your program.

Answer (score 0):

Modifications to the already posted answer by @BrujoBenavides to handle nested tuples:

```erlang
eval({Op, a, b}, #{a := A, b := B}) ->
  eval(Op, A, B);

eval({Op, a, B}, #{a := _} = Map) when is_integer(B) ->
  eval({Op, a, b}, Map#{b => B});

eval({Op, a, Expr}, #{a := _} = Map) ->
  B = eval(Expr, Map),
  eval({Op, a, b}, Map#{b => B});

eval({Op, A, b}, #{b := _} = Map) when is_integer(A) ->
  eval({Op, a, b}, Map#{a => A});

eval({Op, Expr, b}, #{b := _} = Map) ->
  A = eval(Expr, Map),
  eval({Op, a, b}, Map#{a => A});

eval({Op, A, B}, _) when is_integer(A), is_integer(B) ->
  eval({Op, a, b}, #{a => A, b => B});

eval({Op, Expr1, Expr2}, #{} = Map) ->
  %% need to evaluate Expr1 and Expr2 before Op
  A = eval(Expr1, Map),
  B = eval(Expr2, Map#{a => A}),
  eval({Op, a, b}, Map#{a => A, b => B}).

eval(add, A, B) ->
  A+B;

eval(sub, A, B) ->
  A - B;

eval(mul, A, B) ->
  A * B;

eval('div', A, B) ->
  A div B.
```